# Azure functions development and configuration with Azure SignalR Service throws an error message on connection string

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, signalr-hub, azure-functions-runtime, azure-signalr

Here it is the code of the function which is pretty much straight forward:

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public static SignalRConnectionInfo Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]
            HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(
            ConnectionStringSetting = "Endpoint=https://myowntestserver.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=mymaskedaccesskey=;Version=1.0;",
            HubName = "tracking")]
            SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
        {            
            return connectionInfo;
        }
```

When running this code on Visual Studio 2017, I get the following error message:

> [2019-03-27 3:39:14 PM] Error indexing method 'negotiate'
>
> [2019-03-27 3:39:14 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'negotiate'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve the value
>   for property 'SignalRConnectionInfoAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting'.
>   Make sure the setting exists and has a valid value.

local.settings.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

And here it is the host.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

The project file contains the following nuget packages:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.26" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

With all these configurations in place which seem right, not sure why we should get the error message that I quoted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by updating local.settings.json file per the following example:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=Endpoint=https://myowntestserver.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=mymaskedaccesskey=;Version=1.0;""
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

Also, SignalRConnectionInfo.ConnectionStringSetting should be removed from the attribute.